# Search all occurrences of string in linux

Tags: linux

I am new to Linux. I want to search a string in log file. In search result I want only lines which contains that string.

Comment: Off-topic, but: grep wanted-string the-file-name

Comment: Are you looking for `grep`?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$ grep <string> <file>
```

where `<string>` and `<file>` represent the string you are looking for and the name of the file, respectively. You might also want to read up on the grep command as it is very powerful.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
grep --color=auto -n 'string' /path/to/your-log.log
```

`--color=auto` will colorize string occurrence in results and `-n` will add string number. In some cases this might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

The tool you are looking for is `grep`.

```
grep 'string' file
```

Be careful, though, `grep` does not search for occurrences of a string, but rather matches to a regular expression. Some characters have special meaning, read `man grep` for more.

Answer (score 2):

grep -iR string folder  to do this recursively over all files and folders starting from given folder

Answer (score 2):

To print line number and matched line, use command:

```
$awk '/string/{print NR, $0}' <file
```